# What is this encoding and how can I convert in UIWebView

Tags: html, character-encoding, uiwebview

I would like to know how to get my UIWebView to show these characters correctly. The image below is a snapshot of my UIWebView, showing some European language characters are not displaying correctly. I looked at the original web page that this was presented on, and the characters are correct. I suspect there are some meta tags that need to be set in the HTML head used in my UIWebView. but I'm not sure what they would be. Both the original web page and my own HTML are encoded with UTF-8 like this:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
```

[image]

This should be:

> Pour sa première exposition à la Inception Gallery, Christine Barbe
>   affiche une maturité dans son expérimentation en photographie et en
>   vidéo. Elle témoigne d'une nouvelle réflexion profonde liée à notre
>   condition d'humain au sein de notre environnement et à celle de
>   l'intervention du corps dans l'imprégnation de cet environnement.
>   ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data is UTF-8 encoded but UIWebView is interpreting it as if it were ISO-8859-1. This is what makes e.g. “è” rendered as “Ã¨”.

Comment: So is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: I guess there is nothing I can do about it.

Comment: The key is to add a meta tag that specifies utf-8, like this:  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`